# Finding Substring Based on Pattern?

Tags: sql, database, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, wildcard

I have a column of URLs and I'd like to extract the strings after the last "/". For example,
*[www.site.com/string1/string2/string3/**string4***--how](http://www.site.com/string1/string2/string3/**string4***--how) would I extract just string4? All the URLs are different lengths so I'm looking for something dynamic. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    column1 as url,
    regexp_substr(url, '/([^/]+)$',1,1,'e',1) as tail
from values
    ('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72397941/finding-substring-based-on-pattern'),
    ('9/30/21 22:30'),
    ('http://www.example.com/string1/string2/string3/**string4***--how')
;
```

gives:

| URL | TAIL |
| --- | --- |
| [Finding Substring Based on Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72397941/finding-substring-based-on-pattern) | finding-substring-based-on-pattern |
| 9/30/21 22:30 | 21 22:30 |
| http://www.example.com/string1/string2/string3/**string4***--how | **string4***--how |

haha I left a date string from a prior question in there, but it shows the tail match working..

Comment: Thanks, Simeon. What if I want to only extract the URLs that ended in a document extension. For example, www.site.com/string1/string2/string3/**string4.pdf would be string4.pdf.

Comment: `regexp_substr(url, '/([^/]+(\\.pdf))$',1,1,'e',1) as pdfs`

Comment: What if it's .html, .ics, etc..? Is it possible to make it dynamic?

Comment: this is becoming a "how do regex" statically `regexp_substr(url, '/([^/]+((\\.pdf)|(\\.html)|(\\.ics)))$',1,1,'e',1)` dynamically, yes, but then you are building strings which is do able, but very out of scope for this question.